# error: no matching function for call to copy constructor, c++

Tags: c++, copy, copy-constructor, deep-copy, default-constructor

Sorry in advance for what may be a bad post. I've scoured stackoverflow for pre existing posts that answer my question, but although many posts on here are similar, none of them seem to apply to my situation.
I have struct Node, designed to be a container. Class Characters, which has character's name and power.
For some reason without the default constructor the code crash with error:

[image]

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
class Characters {
    public:
        int power;
        std::string name;
        Characters(int power, const std::string &name) : power(power), name(name) {}
        // Characters() : power(0), name("") {}
        //without above line, the code crashes with error: no matching function for call to 'Characters::Characters()' 39 |     Node (const Node<T> &other) {

        Characters(const Characters &other) {
            power=other.power;
            name = other.name;
        }

};

template <typename T>
struct Node {
    T val;
    Node (const T &val) : val(val) {}
    Node (const Node<T> &other) {
        val= other.val;
    }
};

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    Node<Characters> n1(Characters(4, "meh"));
    Node<Characters> n2=n1;

    return 0;
}
```

I have no idea why this occurs without default constructor. I'm probably just bad at using google, but none of the things I search up seems to address my issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [Why should i not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: you are using the member initializer list for one constructor, why not for the other? Members are initialized before the body of the constructor is executed, in absence of a intializer the default constructor must be called, but `Character` has none.

Comment: voting to close as typo. Works when member initializer list is used https://godbolt.org/z/bY74Y1Pos

Comment: most constructors body should look like this: `{}`. Remember that members are **not** initialized in the body of the constructor, but before.

Comment: 463035818_is_not_a_number, can you elaborate on what you mean by "using the member initializer list for one constructor, why not for the other"? Do you mean that I could use member initializers on copy constructors?

Comment: `: val(val)` is a member initializer list. As you can see here https://godbolt.org/z/bY74Y1Pos the error goes away when you use it

Comment: Also note : Adding a custom constructor will remove the (implicitly generated) default constructor. And remember to make constructors with one argument `explicit` too.

Comment: 463035818_is_not_a_number, I see what you mean now, but I always thought that doing val=other.val is same as the member initializer list in constructors? For example, I know in default constructors, this->val = val is same as val(val).

Comment: no its not the same. Members are initialized **before** the body of the constructor is executed. One way to provide an initializer is via the member initializer list. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

Comment: I see, I should clearly look more into this matter then! Thank you!

Comment: no worries. I think its the one detail with the worst "beginner awareness" vs importance quotient ;). I suppose one has to get stuck at least once to understand it. Btw I already wasted my vote, but perhaps others will be so kind to find duplicate questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to 463035818_is_not_a_number for pointing this out!

This below:

```
Node (const Node<T> &other) {
    val= other.val;
}
```

Should be replaced with this.

```
Node (const Node &other) : val(other.val) {        }
```

I misunderstood the usage and property of member initialization list.